# Rendering a html tag in Grid Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid

I need to build a list of shipping number link.

I have finished build the html of the list.

But instead of rendering html. It ouputs the content including html text.

[image]

This is my code to render source for that column:

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            if (isset($item['entity_id'])) {

                /** @var  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
                $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($item['entity_id']);
                $trackCollection = $order->getTracksCollection();

                $str = "";
                foreach ($trackCollection as $trackItem) {
                    if ($trackItem->isCustom()) {
                        $str .= $trackItem->getNumber() . ", ";
                    } else {

                        $str .= '<a href="#" onclick="popWin(\'' . $this->_shippingHelper->getTrackingPopupUrlBySalesModel($trackItem) .
                            '\',\'trackorder\',\'width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes\')">' . $trackItem->getNumber() . '</a>';
                        $str .= '<div id="shipment_tracking_info_response_' . $trackItem->getId() . '"></div>';

                        $str .= ", ";
                    };
                }
                $str = rtrim($str, ", ");
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $str;
            }
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
```

Is there any problem with my code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a a while of digging to magento core code, i firgured that out.

Add this line to column declaration:

```
<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
```

like so:

```
 <column name="shipping_number" class="Eyemagine\Frogfish\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ShippingNumber">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping Number</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also write:

```
<column name="shipping_number" class="Eyemagine\Frogfish\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ShippingNumber"
            sortOrder="40">
   <settings>
      <filter>text</filter>
      <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
      <label translate="true">Shipping Number</label>
   </settings>
</column>
```