# How to add custom HTML in Product Grid Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, html, product-grid

I want to add custom HTML in Magento 2 Product Grid Column.
I have added the column using this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd"> 
<columns name="product_columns">
    <column name="stock_status" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="76">
          <settings>
                <addField>true</addField>
                <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno"/>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
                <label translate="true">Custom Html</label>
         </settings>
   </column>
</columns> 
</listing>
```

[image]

But how to add HTML in this column and how to remove the link on clicking like right now when I click on it it will open the product page I don't want that by onclick.

Comment: Please follow the below link to achieve that. [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188059/rendering-a-html-tag-in-grid-magento-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188059/rendering-a-html-tag-in-grid-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

Need to Create a custom Module :

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

```
<column name="column_name" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Mycolumn">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
        <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Update Data</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
        <item name="fieldClass" xsi:type="string">tnbl_product_update_data</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Mycolumn.php

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
     
    use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
    use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
    use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

     
    use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
     
    class Mycolumn extends Column
    {
        protected $_orderRepository;
        protected $_searchCriteria;
        protected $orderCollectionFactory;

        public function __construct(
         PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
         ContextInterface $context,
         UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
         OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
         SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
         \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory  $orderCollectionFactory,
         array $components = [],
         array $data = [])
        {
         $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
         $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
         $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;

         $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
         parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        }
        public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
        {
          if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
                foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                    $customerOrder = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $item['entity_id']);
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = '<div>Save</div>';
                }
            }
         return $dataSource;
        }
    }
```